# Terraform version discrepancies in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, version, pipeline, upgrade

I have been developing Terraform **v0.14.7** to run via GitLab Pipeline. Everything's been going well until I tried upgrading Terraform to **v0.15.5** (Upgrading above that is beyond my control at the moment). I followed [the advice here](https://www.terraform.io/language/upgrade-guides/0-15) and [a how-to guide here](https://netterminalmachine.com/blog/2021/upgrade-terraform-linux).

When I run `terraform version` on my Terraform server, it shows the proper upgraded version, and I can successfully run `terraform init` each time just fine. However, when I run my pipeline, the version seems to flip between the pre, validate, and plan stages with no consistent pattern. I have it print `terraform version` at the start of each stage, and sometimes pre outputs **0.14.7**, validate outputs **0.15.5**, and then plan flips back to **0.14.7**. Sometimes the order is different as well, such as pre outputting **0.15.5** and the other two stages **0.14.7**. I can't figure out why it's doing this since I can't recreate the problem manually.

It's been very confusing trying to solve - I tried clearing the runner cache, removing the `.terraform` cache and `.terraform.lock.hcl` files, and switching up how I run the init (adding `backend=false` or `lockfile=readonly` flags). Clearing the cache and files allows for one single clean pipeline run, but the next run is always back to being mixed versions. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The closest documented issue I can find is [this issue here](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/issues/158), but a solution was never posted. I have also tried `terraform refresh`, `init -migrate-state`, and `init -reconfigure` with no luck.

Edit 2: I am running Terraform offline with no internet access, so upgrades need to be done manually in case that changes any answer.

Edit 3: I'm unable to paste the exact code but here's as much as I can give, not that the output at the beginning of each stage is `Terraform has been successfully initialized!`:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
- |
  export TF_VAR_pipeline=$CI_PIPELINE_URL
  terraform -chdir="$WORKING_DIR" init -backend=false

pre:
 stage: pre
 script: 
   - which terraform
   - terraform version

validate:
 stage: validate
 script:
   - which terraform
   - terraform version
   - terraform -chdir="$WORKING_DIR" validate

plan:
 stage: plan
 script:
   - which terraform
   - terraform version
   - terraform -chdir="$WORKING_DIR" plan -out=plan_file.txt
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - $WORKING_DIR/plan_file.txt
   when: on success
```

example pre output:

```
$ which terraform
/usr/bin/terraform
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.15.5
on linux_amd64
Saving cache
Creating cache default-3...
...
No URL provided, cache will be not up-loaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally.
Created cache
Cleaning up file based variables
Job succeeded
```

example validate output:

```
$ which terraform
/usr/bin/terraform
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.15.5
on linux_amd64
$ terraform -chdir="$WORKING_DIR" validate
Success! The configuration is valid.
Saving cache
Creating cache default-3...
...
No URL provided, cache will be not up-loaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally.
Created cache
Cleaning up file based variables
Job succeeded
```

example plan output:

```
$ which terraform
/usr/bin/terraform
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.14.7
$ terraform -chdir="$WORKING_DIR" plan -out=plan_file
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
...
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the pipeline along with the outputs you mention?

Comment: @MarkoE added, see edit 3 above

Comment: And which image are you using in the pipeline?

Comment: @MarkoE trying to run Terraform 0.15.5 linux_amd64 if that's what you mean? sorry for lack of knowledge - Terraform development is a responsibility I only recently took on and started learning

Comment: No, I mean how are you running the Gitlab pipeline? Which Docker image are you using?

Comment: @MarkoE no docker unfortunately, i have to go in and run the pipeline manually from the gitlab server on the branch i'm developing on

Comment: Are you caching the previous runs somewhere? If so, is there a way to remove the cache without breaking anything?

Comment: Do you have multiple gitlab servers?

Comment: @MarkoE Good question, I'll have to find out and see if we can script clearing it out. I'm confident it wouldn't break anything

Comment: @harshavmb we only have the one

Comment: Update: clearing the gitlab runner cache as well as all files in gitlab-runner/cache did not work. actually, all pipeline runs since doing that keep reverting back to the old terraform version (version on the terraform server still reports new updated one). i'm not sure where it's pulling the 0.14.7 version from anymore, is there anywhere else i should look for stored versions?

Comment: Do you have the `terraform.old` binary in `/usr/bin/` dir by any chance?
May be symlinks to the old binary somewhere?

Comment: @harshavmb i confirmed terraform.old is no longer in /usr/bin - i originally moved that file to /var/tmp to get it out of the way then removed it altogether. i'll search around again in case there's anything else remaining

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this issue was never solved. I believe it had something to do with the Gitlab cache but I couldn't figure it out. I ended up spinning up a new Terraform server instance and installing a fresh gitlab-runner, all seems to be working well now.